# How to (MySQL) multiply columns and then the sum rows?

Tags: mysql

I've got this table:

```
id    |   payment_id   | quantity  |  unit cost
1           633             1            750  
2           633             1            750 
3           632             2            750 
4           632             2            750
```

What I need is :

```
payemnt_id  |   total
    633           1500
    632           3000
```

You can also think of this as Countries and then you are trying to find the total for each Country.  I was sure there were some tutorials like this but could not find by STFW.

Comment: Why you have in `payment_id` total `3000`?

Comment: total for `632` is 1500, isn't it? you want to sum with rest?

Comment: 750*2 + 750*2 = 3000 ?

Comment: hmmm, you need to explain better , -1

Comment: I think you should read a little better.

Comment: Instead of payment_id think of say country and you were totalling sales for each country.  So in the first table above "country" occurs more than once.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can simply put the formula (expression) inside `SUM`:

```
SELECT payment_id, SUM(`unit cost` * quantity) AS total
FROM myTable
GROUP BY payment_id
```

Comment: Should be a little faster than mine.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    payment_id, 
    SUM(subtotal) AS total
 FROM(
    SELECT
        payment_id,
        (unit_cost * quantity) AS subtotal
) AS t1
GROUP BY 
payment_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT payemnt_id, SUM(`unit cost` * quantity) as total
FROM Table1
GROUP BY payemnt_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COALESCE (SUM(cost_field * quantity_field),0) AS tot FROM Table_Name
```

I Think This One Is Good, Why ?
Because If Their is No Result It Will Give You Zero