# Achieve this only with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

```
$query = "SELECT stake, cuota, ID FROM tips WHERE ID = 1";
```

***My table***

```
+------------------------+------+-----+---------+
| id                     |stake |cuota| ID      | 
+------------------------+------+-----+---------+
| 1                      |3.250 |5.00 | 1       | 
| 2                      |3.000 |5.00 | 1       |
+------------------------+------+-----+---------+
```

Everything works perfect in PHP.

but I'd like to do it with mysql in a query.

I would like to have it in MySQL without having to use PHP -> this result * **21.25** *

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($fromMysql as $row):
$sum+= $row['stake'] * $row['cuota'] - $row['stake'];  
/*individual sum.  first = 11.25 and second = 10.00*/
endforeach;
echo $sum; /* = 21.25 */
```

Comment: Maybe like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806545/how-to-mysql-multiply-columns-and-then-the-sum-rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm not very familiar with PHP, so I might not understand properly your problem, but as I understand the result should be 25 instead of 21.25.

Anyway, in `MySQL` you should do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(stake * cuota - stake) FROM [your_table]
```

This Query will give you a result of 25.
To have a query with your expected result (21.25) you can do:

```
SELECT SUM(stake * cuota - cuota) FROM [your_table]
```

Comment: `SELECT SUM(stake * cuota - stake) FROM tips where resultado = 1`

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know this is not possible and this shouldn't be done in sql since it is a data query language not a language for calculating prices.

I think it is perfectly fine to use the solution you currently have

```
foreach ($fromMysql as $row) {
    $sum+= $row['stake'] * $row['cuota'] - $row['stake'];
}
```

This might look a little cleaner

Comment: Then why does SQL have functions like `SUM()` that do exactly this?